# WAMP Server mySQL data type? mySQL Database not updating in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

I'm writing a PHP page that runs on a server and accepts a few POST paramaters and adds them to a server after validating them using REGEX. For some reason, my server (using WAMP server) is showing an empty result set after the code runs successfully and after I'm redirected to the page at the end.

I think it could be my code, but it could also perhaps be the way the server is setup, currently, all my columns are of type "int(11)" and I don't know which type to choose.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["pnumber"])){
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $number = $_POST["pnumber"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=daythree", "root",  "");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if( preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}$/", $number) && 
        preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]{2,}[\sA-Za-z]*$/", $name) && 
        preg_match("/^[A-z0-9_\-]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z.]{2,4}$/", $email)){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO daythree ('name', 'email', 'number') VALUES ('. $name .', '. $email. ', '. $number .')";

        header("Location: evilmasterminds.php");
        die();
    }

}
```

Thanks and apologies for any trouble.

Comment: `Int` is not going to be the right choice for `name` and `email` and the sql statement is wrong - should perhaps be more like `$sql = "INSERT INTO daythree ('name', 'email', 'number') VALUES ('{$name}', '{$email}', '{$number}')";`

Comment: and why, when you are using PDO do you not use prepared statements - you are negating the one thing that protects against malicious sql injection by embedding POST variables in the sql? Also, do not use single quotes around column names - use the backtick instead!

Comment: I changed the $sql line to that; I've only been coding since a few months and this is more as an experiment for me to edit databases for personal use, so I'm not that worried about the security side of it :)

Also, thanks for the help! :) By the way, what should I change Int to? There are quite a few options and I'm not sure which would be right :(

Comment: There is so much wrong here that its difficult to know where to start

Comment: Your connection string is wrong

Comment: Your INSERT command is using single quote instead of the correct backticks

Comment: You are doing **absolutely no error checking**

Comment: Hit the books and stop guessing

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but as you use PDO perhaps something more like the following - it should at least point you in the right direction.

```
if(isset($_POST["name"],$_POST["email"],$_POST["pnumber"])){

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $number = $_POST["pnumber"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];


    try{
        $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=daythree", "root",  "");
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        if( preg_match( "/^[0-9]{10}$/", $number ) && 
            preg_match( "/^[A-Za-z]{2,}[\sA-Za-z]*$/", $name ) && 
            preg_match( "/^[A-z0-9_\-]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z.]{2,4}$/", $email ) ){


            $sql='insert into `daythree` (`name`,`email`,`number`) values (:name,:email,:number);';
            $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':name'     =>  $name,
                ':email'    =>  $email,
                ':number'   =>  $number
            ));

            exit( header("Location: evilmasterminds.php") );
        }

    }catch( PDOException $e ){
        exit('Error: '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

As for column types `name` and `email` should almost certainly be `varchar` whilst `number` could be `int` depending upon actual format used in the numbers you receive - again a varchar column might be more suitable.

update:
code changed to account for point made by @riggsfolly regarding exceptions

Comment: Pretty sure the connection string is incorrect as well, and it is not tested as correctly connected in any way

Comment: As OP is setting MYSQL to throw execptions it would be a good idea to put the PDO statements in a try/catch block